# connection String is not right. Please visit portal for references

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mysql-database

I am not able to login into my application on azure environment.I have added driver class, username and password in my application properties file. I am using my sql workbench but everytime I login its showing me the error that connection string is not right. 
I have entered all correct details as shows in azure sql database in my app properties. 
please help?

Comment: Have you visited the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-workbench) page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly is make sure your connection string is right, you could go to portal get all [connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-connection-string#get-the-connection-string-details-from-the-azure-portal).

Then make sure configure the right settings. When connecting from Azure App Service to Azure MySQL, you could choose `Allow access to Azure services` option will allow the app service to connect to the MySQL server. Or you could create a firewall rule to explicitly allow outbound IPs. The details about how to configure, you could refer to this site:[Connect an existing Azure App Service to Azure Database for MySQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-connect-webapp#solution-1---allow-azure-services).

Comment: @shagun dhiman, any more problems? If this could help you, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please upgrade your MySQL Workbench software to the latest version.

Please try to connect as shown on below image:

[image]

You can also use MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE, change your CMD directory to "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE". There you can use mysql.exe file and connect to Azure Database for Mysql.

Comment: I am able to connect through my sql workbench. but in my application, I am not able to login into my application. I have written my database connection in a properties file but everytime i login it shows connection string is not right.